# Querydsl with MongoDB usage

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, querydsl

I have the following Mongo configuration in a Java Spring project:

```
    @Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration {

    public static int allocateRandomPort() {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(0);
            int port = server.getLocalPort();
            server.close();
            return port;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to acquire a random free port", e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("DB.TRACE", "true");
        return new EmbeddedMongoBuilder()
                .version("2.6.0")
                .bindIp("127.0.0.1")
                .port(allocateRandomPort())
                .build();
    }
}
```

To start building queries using the Querydsl Mongodb module, the [documentation](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02s07.html) says that:

```
Morphia morphia;
Datastore datastore;
// ...
QUser user = new QUser("user");
MorphiaQuery<User> query = new MorphiaQuery<User>(morphia, datastore, user);
```

I have no ideia on how to create the instance of the MorphiaQuery class. Should the `Datastore` object be a inject Mongo instance? And how about `Morphia` object? [Other tutorials](http://www.hascode.com/2014/02/creating-elegant-typesafe-queries-for-jpa-mongodbmorphia-and-lucene-using-querydsl/) I found online create the instance as:

```
Morphia morphia = new Morphia()
        .map(Book.class, Author.class, Tag.class);
```

I would like to build the queries inside a `Spring Data MongoDB repository`. Is there a fully functional example somewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morphia and Spring Data Mongodb are alternative object mappers for Querydsl Mongodb. Querydsl itself bundles with the Morphia integration, for Spring Data Mongodb you will need to refer to the [references docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.7.0.RELEASE/reference/html/) to set it up.

Comment: I ended using this tutorial, which proved extremely useful: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-five-querydsl/